# SQLite in android order by date and time not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm currently developing an application for android and I'm trying to get the last entry in my database ordered by a column that contains a String with the date and time.

My problem is that the result of the query is always the first date and not the last one.

I already tried ordered my column by "date", "datetime" and by "DESC" and "ASC".

the following is the query to create the table that contains the date in question

```java
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TIMBRAGE="CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_TIMBRAGE + "(" + COLUMN_T_TIMBRAGE_PK_TIMBRAGE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_T_TIMBRAGE_DATETIMBRAGE + " DATETIME NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_T_TIMBRAGE_INOUT + " INT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_T_TIMBRAGE_FK_EMPLOYE + " INT NOT NULL, "+ "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_T_TIMBRAGE_FK_EMPLOYE + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_EMPLOYE + "("+COLUMN_T_EMPLOYE_PK_EMPLOYE+") "
```

here is my formatter for the dates

```java
SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy'-'HH:mm:ss", Locale.FRANCE);
```

here is how I'm adding into this table

```java
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_T_TIMBRAGE_DATETIMBRAGE, FORMATTER.format(timbrage.getDateTimbrage()));
        values.put(COLUMN_T_TIMBRAGE_INOUT, timbrage.getInOut());
        values.put(COLUMN_T_TIMBRAGE_FK_EMPLOYE, timbrage.getFK_Employe());

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_TIMBRAGE, null, values);
        db.close();
```

and finally here is my query that should get the last entry

```java
String query2 = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_TIMBRAGE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_T_TIMBRAGE_FK_EMPLOYE + " =  \"" + FK_Employe + "\"" + " ORDER BY datetime("+ COLUMN_T_TIMBRAGE_DATETIMBRAGE +") ASC LIMIT 1 ";
                Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery(query2, null);
```

The result that I get is

> "Thu May 23 15:34:58 GMT+02:00 2019"

but I should get

> "Thu May 23 15:56:32 GMT+02:00 2019"

Comment: Change the date format to: `yyyy.MM.dd'-'HH:mm:ss` or something similar, because the format you use is not comparable. SQLite does not know anything about dates, so it treats everything as TEXT.

Comment: If you use one of the formats supported by [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) you get as an added bonus the ability to meaningfully sort timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  * FROM  + YOUR_TABLE_NAME +  ORDER BY + YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN_NAME + DESC
```

And I have a suggestion that you should use `DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as your `DATETIME` column type. This auto-updates the `DATETIME` whenever you insert or update the row.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving date as a String, it is a good idea to convert said date to milliseconds since 01 Jan 1970. This way, the sorting is very straightforward and comparing numbers is more efficient. You can then, upon querying the data convert the milliseconds to a formatted Date.